# What versions of avro and parquet formats does Spark support?

Tags: apache-spark, avro, parquet

Does Spark 2.0 support avro and parquet files? What versions?

I have downloaded `spark-avro_2.10-0.1.jar` and got this error during load:

```
Name: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
Message: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.TableScan
StackTrace:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:349)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:727)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1182)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:602)
```

Comment: what scala version is your spark compiled on ?

Comment: its scala v: 2.11

Comment: How did you specify spark-avro to use in your Spark application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just using the wrong dependency. You should use the `spark-avro` dependency that is compiles with Scala 2.11. You can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-avro_2.11).

As for parquet, it's supported without any dependency to add to your application.

Answer (score 2):

> Does spark 2.0 supports avro and parquet files?

Avro format is not supportd in Spark 2.x out of the box. You have to use an external package, e.g. [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro).

```
Name: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
Message: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.TableScan
```

The reason for `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` is that you used `spark-avro_2.10-0.1.jar` that was compiled for **Scala 2.10**, but Spark 2.0 uses **Scala 2.11** by default. This inevitably leads to this `IncompatibleClassChangeError` error.

You should rather load the spark-avro package using `--packages` command line option (as described in the official documentation of spark-avro in [With spark-shell or spark-submit](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro#with-spark-shell-or-spark-submit)):

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0
```

> using `--packages` ensures that this library and its dependencies will be added to the classpath. The `--packages` argument can also be used with `bin/spark-submit`.

---

Parquet format is the default format when loading or saving datasets.

```
// loading parquet datasets
spark.read.load

// saving in parquet format
mydataset.write.save
```

You may want to read up on [Parquet Files](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) support in the official documentation:

> Spark SQL provides support for both reading and writing Parquet files that automatically preserves the schema of the original data.

Parquet 1.8.2 is used (as you can see in Spark's [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml#L134))